# Import error with tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy

I am new to python and anaconda.

I am using Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 15 2016, 15:29:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)].  The version of the notebook server is 4.2.1.

When I issue the following command

```
import tweepy
```

it runs successfully.

But when I try to run the following command

```
%%file test.py

import tweepy
```

Its getting save as test.py

When I issue the following command

```
!python test.py
```

I am getting the following error.

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
            import tweepy
        ImportError: No module named tweepy
```

I am able to see tweepy folders in my anaconda installation directory

D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

```
 tweepy-3.5.0.dist-info
 tweepy
```

Where am I going wrong.  Kindly guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have multiple versions of python installed on my machine this issue exists.  So when I point to the correct directory of my python installation, its working fine.